# Trying to update an Android app to the Google Play Store, cannot sign with original keyfile

Tags: android, google-play

I published an app about 6 years ago (before App Bundles) and followed a process like this:

```
1. make keystore:
  keytool -genkey -v -keystore xxx -alias xxx -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
2. create platforms\android\ant.properties containing
  key.store="\path\to\keystore"
  key.alias=xxx
  key.store.password=xxx
  key.alias.password=xxx
3. build release apk
4. Build it with ant
  ant release
5. Sign it
  jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore xxx
6. Zip align
  zipalign -v 4 xxx -release-unsigned.apk xxx.apk
```

I no longer have the computer where I built it, so I started a new project in Android Studio, pasted in all the code, fixed some bugs, and am trying to release an update.  However, all of my attempts to use it have failed. I **do** have the keystore file but all of my attempts to use it have failed.

I am using the "Generate Signed Bundle or APK" dialog wizard in Android Studio.  I can successfully create an app bundle or .apk, so I know I am using the right password for the keystore.

- APK - when I upload the .apk to Google, I get: "You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s): SHA1: 52:.... and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s): SHA1: F7:..."
- App Bundle - If I follow the "Use existing app signing key from Android Studio" option under Setup/App Integrity/App signing, and upload the `private_key.pepk` that was created when I produced the app bundle, it is rejected: "The private key doesn't match the current app certificate "
- App Bundle 2 - If I follow the "Use existing app signing key from Java KeyStore" option, I am prompted to download pepk.jar and do this:

`java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=encrypted_private_key_path --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a`

But I am unclear on what `--encryptionkey` means in this context.  Should I have an encryption key saved  from when I initially published it?  I don't recall having one, I thought the keystore and the keystore password was all I needed, and it looks that is all I saved.

Comment: It sounds like the keystore file you have contains a different key than the one you originally used to sign your app. If that's indeed the case, you are SOL. Prior to Google Play managed keys, there was no way to recover from losing the key to sign your app other than releasing it as a completely new app on the store.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right keystore?  Or that you didn't upload a debug build by accident 6 years ago?  (Debug builds are signed and can be uploaded to play, but they would use a different keystore).

Comment: I am 99% sure I have the right keystore.  I actually have two, one used for the debug build and one for the production build, and have tried both, same result.

Comment: One possible sol would be to remove current app from prod, change packagename and reupload with gp managed keys. You might not like that though.